# How to get page's visual section's width and height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, height, width

How to get them by using JS and jQuery?

I know `$(window).innerWidth()` can get. But I don't hope it contains the width or height of the scroll bar.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/width/):

```
$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
$(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
```

If you add `overflow:hidden` to the body of this page (so there's no scrollbar), then run `$(window).width()` in a JS console, notice this value increases!

Answer (score 2):

i Have found the best way is with Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var height = document.body.offsetHeight;
var width = document.body.offsetWidth;

//code goes here
</script>
```

Bear in mind that when you use these, they return an integer so if you are going to use them to apply a style to another object or element then you will have to append them as so:

```
var newHeight=height + 'px';
var newWidth=width + 'px';
```